# Is the Hodge Map Unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, hodge-theory, inner-product

Let $(V,< \cdot, \cdot >)$ be  an inner product space over a field ${K}$. As usual, we can extend $< \cdot, \cdot >$ to a mapping on the exterior algebra of $V$ using the usual matrix determinant, and we then get a corresponding Hodge map $\ast$. Now is it true in general that $\ast$ is unitary, that is, does it hold that
$$
< \ast(v), \ast(w) > = <v, w >,
$$
and if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A cheap way is to choose an orthonormal basis $(e_1,\ldots ,e_n)$ of $V$ (replacing $K$ by its algebraic closure). Then the $e_I$ for $I\subset [1,n]$ and $\#I=p$ form an orthonormal basis of $\wedge^pV$, and $\ast$ maps $e_I$ to $\pm e_{I^c}$ (as usual, I put $e_I=e_{i_1}\wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_p}$ for $I=\{i_1,\ldots ,i_p\}\subset [1,n]$).